# Excel - Error column multiple errors in one cell

Tags: excel

I am creating a powershell script to upload data into SQL server via a standardised excel spreadsheet. I wanted to put some error checking in the excel spreadsheet so that if it links incorrectly i can put it all back on the user who filled out the spreadsheet.

As an example here is part of the Company section of the excel spreadsheet:

[image]

This error refers to the manager pin column (D2), where it does not exist in the manager upload sheet:

[image]

The above is using the following formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Manager'!$A$2:$A$1048576, [@[Manager Pin]])>0, "", "Manager Pin Does Not Exist")
```

What i want is to have multiple errors returned based on the fields with a newline separator between each one, so in image one if both the manager PIN and the company PIN are non existent, then the result in ERRORS (A2) would be:

[image]

This way i can exclude any import where the error section is not null on the SQL side of things.

--------- Bitwise error set:

As an example for a bitwise error set for 3 of the possible errors:

```
0 - No errors
1 - Manager pin not valid
2 - Company pin not valid
3 - Manager pin not valid
    Company pin not valid
4 - Company name is null - required field
5 - Manager pin not valid
    Company name is null - required field
6 - Company pin not valid
    Company name is null - required field
7 - Manager pin not valid
    Company pin not valid
    Company name is null - required field
```

So the above errors would be created on a separate sheet in the spreadsheet. Then i can create a hidden column in the spreadsheet that calculates the error code. After that all i should have to do is reference the error code in the ERRORS column based on the error code in the hidden column.

Comment: I would suggest making a bitwise error number set (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, etc) so that by looking at the total you can always tell which errors have occurred. e.g. a 7 would be errors 1, 2 and 4; a 5 would be errors 1 and 4; a 10 would be errors 2 and 8. If the bitwise construct is created properly, any sum can have only a single combination of error codes. A 0 (zero) means error code success. Besides, summing is easier than string concatenation.

Comment: Thats a really good idea, whats the best way to do this? have a separate hidden cell that calculates the error number and a list of error responses on a separate sheet then just reference the error response in the errors column?

Comment: Well, you would start with a table of error codes with descriptions and number from 0 for error success through 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc for as many as you need. I'l have to look a little deeper into your existing methods before advising further.

Comment: Ive added a sample error set in an edit.

Comment: One possibility would be to simply use the failed field index number in a bitwise error number. e.g. Fields (aka Columns) 1, 2, 3, 4, etc would be error 1, 2, 4, 8... etc. An error description could be constructed using the column header label.

Comment: Thats what i have done, i have just created individual columns for each error and returning an integer value, then using a vlookup on the total count. If you want to make this an answer i will make it the accepted answer. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate the results of the two separate, similar checks. Assumning you have a `Company` sheet with similar layout of the `Manager` sheet:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Manager!$A$2:$A$1048576, [@[Manager Pin]])>0,
     "", "Manager Pin Does Not Exist")
& IF(COUNTIF(Company!$A$2:$A$1048576, [@[Company Pin]])>0,
     "", CHAR(10)&"Company Pin Does Not Exist")
```

By the way, why use `$A$2:$A$1048576` and not simply `A:A`? If you have a header row in the serched sheet wont match anyway, so let us simplify it.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Manager!A:A, [@[Manager Pin]])>0, "", "Manager Pin Does Not Exist")
& IF(COUNTIF(Company!A:A, [@[Company Pin]])>0, "", CHAR(10)&"Company Pin Does Not Exist")
```

p.s.The `MATCH` alternative:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH([@[Manager Pin]], Manager!A:A,0)), "", "Manager Pin Does Not Exist")
& IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH([@[Company Pin]], Company!A:A,0)), "", CHAR(10)&"Company Pin Does Not Exist")
```

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful, i have never used the Match function so ill have to take a look at it. As for the cell ranges, no idea why i didn't just use A:A. The pins will always be sorted, they are an auto-increment field for each entry using =ROW()-1

Comment: The issue with this is that, in the company sheet on this spreadsheet there are 4 fields i need to check and post to the errors cell. This means i would need to have a huge function to go through each and every possible outcome of invalid fields.

Comment: @OwainEsau in that case `Match` will be much faster using binary search if the data is big enough. If you're interested I can add the match solution.

Comment: @OwainEsau I added the `Match` version but it is not the binary search one. However since you have to check too many fields, probably you need to tackle the whole problem differently.

Comment: Yeah, i'm most likely going to go with the bitwise error number set advised by Jeeped. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the [`TEXTJOIN` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) (Excel 2016+), you can join them by line feed character:

```
= TEXTJOIN( CHAR(10), TRUE, IF(...), IF(...) )
```

Comment: I do yes, but there is no guarantee that the people i send this excel sheet to would, most of them probably won't.

Comment: @OwainEsau good point, but I can't think of any other way to avoid the extra new lines that can occur between messages (other than VBA UDF). BTW I think that `@[]` works only in Excel 2010+, and structured references `[]` in Excel 2007+